# How to apply CSS flex property to nested element

Tags: css, flexbox

**This is my code**

```
<div class="site">
<header>
    This is my header
</header>

<div class="content">
    <div class="inside">
        <div id="first">
            </div> 
        <div id="last">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<footer>
    This is my footer
</footer>
</div>
```

**Styles**

```
header {
  background-color: blue;
}
footer {
  background-color: brown;
}

.site {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.content {
  flex: 1;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
}
#first {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 40px;
}
#last {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
}
.inside {

}
```

This gives me a output like this.
[image]

What I need is **green colored div should go to the bottom of the page** and it should on top of the footer.
and my yellow colored div should stretch and fill up the reaming purple space.
meaning there should be no purple color.

How do I achieve this using CSS flex properties?

Comment: Is this the result you were looking for? https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/MGraZw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this. You don't need the div with `inside` class.

```css
header {
  background-color: blue;
}
footer {
  background-color: brown;
}

.site {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.content {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#first {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 1;
}
#last {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
}
.inside {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="site">
<header>
    This is my header
</header>

<div class="content">
    <div id="first">
        First
        </div> 
    <div id="last">
    last
        </div>
    </div>
<footer>
    This is my footer
</footer>
</div>
```